# What that mean 2>&1 << EOL

Tags: bash, shell

I have below shell script.
It works fine on one host. on second one it not works.
When I remove 2>&1 << ‘EOF’ it works fine on second host.
What that mean 2>&1 << ‘EOF’? Why it works fine on one, but not work on second host?

Thanks

```
start () {
    case ${1} in
     APP1)
        ssh -q user@host 2>&1 << ‘EOF’
        exit $?
EOF
     ;;
     APP2)
        ssh -q user@host 2>&1 << ‘EOF’
        exit $?
EOF
     ;;
}
```

Comment: Are there any differences for `shell` environments of the 2 hosts? Do you use the same `shell` on the 2 hosts?

Comment: Shell is same on both hosts

Comment: Make sure to use correct single quotes around EOF!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere out of here.

Since you have two different hosts, and the script is working with `ssh`, I would suggest to look at the network first. It is possible that one host has connection to the target host, and another does not.

The key `-q` you have in your ssh command suppress most warnings and diagnostics ssh can give, and `2>&1` redirects the stderr into stdout, but since you already suppressed them - the redirection is kind of pointless.

The  `<< 'EOF'` is not a culprit here. At least I cannot imagine how it can be. Unless the shell on one of the hosts is really broken and does not know how to handle [Here Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in the quoted variation.

Comment: The target shell doesn't even know that its input comes from a here doc, does it? (And I guess it would only be "the quoted variation" if the OP had actual quotes in the script.)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to ssh connection issue.

Comment: So, the issue was something that was not part of the question?